# How to find Logos for payment providers?

Tags: images, finance

I am implementing a payment system (based on Stripe Elements). Each payment provider as SEPA, Giropay, Sofort, Klarna, credit card, etc. needs its own brand logo icon, to be distinguishable. I spent multiple hours searching for these resources.

Searching, checking licensing, reformatting to or from svg, png, creating black and white versions of the logo. etc. And the whole time I had this nagging feeling that there must be a better way. Does a central resource for such Logos exist that I didn't find yet? If not, what is the way?

Answer (score 1):

Just [searching for `payment service provider logos`](https://www.google.com/search?q=payment+service+provider+logos) gives a couple of resources.

[This one](https://www.flaticon.com/packs/payments-logos) from flaticon.com might do the trick:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. The flaticon resource doesn't provide the colored versions of the icons. And some of the most sommon payment providers in europe are not present, e.g. SEPA, Sofort, Giropay. Definitely better than nothing, but not yet the holy grail of icons ;)